# circle inside a rect with a button click

Tags: python-2.7, button, pygame, geometry

I am trying to create a game and i have to make this plexus made of buttons. Every time the player clicks the button, it should appear a small circle inside the pressed button. I tried to make a draw_circle function but when i place it on the action variable inside the buttons, I get this errror. Global name x is not defined.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 900
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (250,0,0)
green = (0,250,0)
bright_red =(200,0,0)
bright_green = (0,200,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("A MATH'S GAME")


def draw_circle():
    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay,black,(x,y),100)


def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
        action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))


    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def messgae_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("Arial",60)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()


def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A math's game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,draw_circle)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()

def game_loop():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",50)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A math's game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),100)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button(None,200,250,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,200,300,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,200,350,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,200,400,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,200,450,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,200,500,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,250,250,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,250,300,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,250,350,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,250,400,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,250,450,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,250,500,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,300,250,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,300,300,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,300,350,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,300,400,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,300,450,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,300,500,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,350,250,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,350,300,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,350,350,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,350,400,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,350,450,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,350,500,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,400,250,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,400,300,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,400,350,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,400,400,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,400,450,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,400,500,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,450,250,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,450,300,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,450,350,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,450,400,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,450,450,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,450,500,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,500,250,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,500,300,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,500,350,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,500,400,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,500,450,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,500,500,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,550,250,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,550,300,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,550,350,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,550,400,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,550,450,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,550,500,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,600,250,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,600,300,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,600,350,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,600,400,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,600,450,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,600,500,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,650,250,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,650,300,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,650,350,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,650,400,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,650,450,50,50,bright_red,red,None)
        button(None,650,500,50,50,bright_red,red,None)

        pygame.display.update()

pygame.init()
game_intro()
```

Comment: Please give the full error, including the traceback.  The location of the error is essential to know what the problem is, except with very short pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `button("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,draw_circle)` you aren't giving `draw_circle` a value for `x` or `y`, so they are, in fact, not defined. You need to pass these down to to the `draw_circle` function.

Inside of your `button` function, pass the arguments down to `draw_circle` like:

```
if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
        action(x, y)
```

Comment: Also, typical Python coding styles dictate that you should change `action != None` to `action is not None`

Comment: Dang, you beat me by seven minutes!  =P

Comment: @Douglas lol I'm a nerd, I basically just browse StackOverflow when I'm bored lmao

Comment: I do the same thing! XD

Comment: @Douglas StackOverflow helped me a TON when I first started programming when I was like 15 or something (WOW that was so many years ago) so now I'm giving back lol

Comment: Well, StackOverflow helped me a lot when I was 9, and NOW I'm 15, and giving back. =D